# Layer was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I followed the code that I found on [this page](https://haptik.ai/tech/offline-on-device-ml-text-classification/).

When I copy-paste the code, I get an error:

```
ValueError: Layer batch_normalization_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor.
```

https://github.com/shantanuo/stack_question/blob/master/haptik_chatbot.ipynb

What is the reason that I get an error unlike the blog writer?

Comment: Please put the whole traceback and code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not giving input to your Dense layer.

```
feature_input = Input(shape=(sentences_features.shape[1],))
dense = Dense(128, activation=activations.relu)
merged = BatchNormalization()(dense)
```

Try:

```
dense = Dense(128, activation=activations.relu)(feature_input)
```

Comment: Thanks. But Now getting different error - NameError: name 'Model' is not defined. https://github.com/shantanuo/stack_question/blob/master/haptik_chatbot.ipynb

Comment: Have you imported Model?  I don't see that in code, _[from keras.models import Model]_

Comment: Still getting an error: ValueError: Input tensors to a Model must come from keras.layers.Input

Comment: _model = Model(inputs=[word_index], outputs=preds)_ in this line _word_index_ is external variable. You can not use it like this. It has to be passed to model via Input layer.